# Regex Expression Parsing in c#

Tags: .net, regex

While matching string with regex pattern throws exception

```
string input = "CheckConvexity: Zone=CEILING VOID ZONE STORY 1, Surface=CEILING VOID LIVING:SLAB 2.2 931D4 is non-convex.  ...vertex 4 to vertex 5 to vertex 6  ...vertex 4=[5.41,15.05,3.90]  ...vertex 5=[1.19,10.82,3.90]  ...vertex 6=[-2.16,14.17,3.90]";
string pattern ="CheckConvexity:\ Zone=[^]*,\ Surface=[^]*\ is\ non-convex\.\ \.\.\.vertex\ [^]*\ to\ vertex\ [^]*\ to\ vertex\ [^]*\ \.\.\.vertex\ [^]*=\[[^]*]\ \.\.\.vertex\ [^]*=\[[^]*]\ \.\.\.vertex\ [^]*=\[[^]*]\ \.\.\.vertex\ [^]*\ to\ vertex\ [^]*\ to\ vertex\ [^]*\ \.\.\.vertex\ [^]*=\[[^]*]\ \.\.\.vertex\ [^]*=\[[^]*]\ \.\.\.vertex\ [^]*=\[[^]*]" ;

Regex.IsMatch(input,pattern,System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

Below is the exception -

> A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred
>   in System.dll Additional information: parsing "[^]*Errors\ found\
>   getting\ inputs.\ Previous\ error(s)\ cause\ program\
>   termination." - Unterminated [] set.

Help me to resolve this.

Comment: can you please show the _code_ that raises the exception and the _exact_ exception message?

Comment: What do you mean by `[^]` in your regex?

Comment: Firstly, You don't have semi colons after declaring variables. Secondly, What do you want your pattern match exactly ?

Comment: You will need to escape those backslashes or else the regex engine will not see them as they are removed by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `[^]` doesn't mean anything. A `[^abc]` would match any character *except* a, b or c. You didn't provide the "except" part, according to the regex engine.

If you mean to match the `^` character, use `\^` (escaping the backslash according to your language) as a plain `^` has a special meaning.

And if you want to match any characters (judging by your sample), use `.*`. A `.` matches any single character, the `*` is a quantifier that specified "zero or more of the previous".